# How to store and retrieve text data in a formatted way?

Tags: java, html, sql-server

I am building my website using Java and the [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) database. It is just like Stack Overflow where I have to store questions, answers, comments and images.

I am not able to store the text in a formatted way in SQL Server's text data type. Neither I am able to display it in a formatted way like Stack Overflow does. All solutions I've found so far concerns only PHP and MySQL. No help for Java and SQL Server. When I retrieve the text to display on web page it's all a mess. All I want to display the question and answers on my website just like Stack Overflow does. I'm attaching an image of my display page here to explain my problem. [It is the image of a text ousput display from my website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9koeO.png)

[Image of output display from my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1yGk.png)

Comment: What exactly is the output shown in the image? Is that the information stored in a row in the SQL table? Could you show us how do you execute the query in Java?

Comment: Yes, it was the information stored in a row in SQL table. I'm editing my question to show you query.

Comment: This is it                                                                                                             try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM QNA");
            while (rs.next()) {
                TextBean bean = new TextBean();
                bean.setText(rs.getString(1));
                list.add(bean);
            }

Comment: and for display <div id="qa" name="qa" style="min-height: 4px; height: auto; width: 750px;margin: 0 auto;background-color:#f0f0f5;"><%=pb.getText() %></div><br/>

Answer (score 0):

First off: from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187993.aspx), the "text", "ntext" and "image" data types will be soon removed from SQL Server, so you should avoid using them.

For text, use varchar(max); for ntext, use nvarchar(max) and for image, use varbinary (max).

I know from developing SSIS packages that SQL Server processes text types as a stream of non-unicode characters. So what I advise you to try is:

1. Change your datatype to nvarchar(max), to support unicode characters, what might be your problem;
2. Try to convert your nvarchar(max) to a string type before displaying. You can [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx) the data using SQL Server, even in a stored procedure.

Comment: I am already using varbinary(max) for images. I'll try nvarchar(max) for text and check whether it solves my problem. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Gaurav Mahindra: if it does not work, try converting the nvarchar(max) to string type. You can use a stored procedure in SQL Server to retrieve the nvarchar(max) and convert before giving it back to you. In SSIS, when I tried to display "text" data types, it would display something similar to your problem - "<Long text>" - what I did was convert the text to string using a method in C#, which is the language used in SSIS, you could do the same. Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay. I don't know much about stored procedures. It will take some time to do this. But I'll do this. Thanks

Comment: I tried nvarchar(max) in place of text. It changed nothing. And what is SSIS by the way.

Comment: @Gaurav Mahindra: SSIS is the SQL Server Integration Services, basically a data warehouse utility from Microsoft that comes with most SQL Server distributions. You develop packages to perform ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) processes in data provided by multiple sources and run them as scheduled jobs.